# EFcore Joining InMemory Table for duplication of entry

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Contrary to most questions about joining to an inmemory table in efcore, my objective is not to reduce the amount of records returned, but to actually increase it.

I have an object that has an `ins` and an `outs` property.

because of the project it is on, theses need to be in the same object. but in my case, I need to consider both of these properties as seperate entities. (kindof how you would use them in a pivot table in excel)

my immediate objective is to transform the `{ins:x, outs:y}` into two lines : `{type:'ins', value:x}` and `{type:'outs', value:y}`

The reason I need them seperate is because I'm later joining on other table differently depending on the type.

in SQL, this is how I would do things :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.type = 'ins' THEN d.ins ELSE d.outs END, t.type
FROM Data d
JOIN (VALUES ('ins'), ('outs')) as t (type) on 1=1;
```

`(VALUES (1,0), (3,5)) as d (ins, outs)` instead of `Data d` can be used as an exemple.

I need to do that with linq in order to "duplicate" all lines (with specific data attached).

These lines are then used later to make other joins.

What I would have liked is something like that :

```
var q = from d in data
        from type in new string[] {"ins","outs"}
        select new {type, value = (type == "ins" ? d.ins : d.outs)}
```

but it isn't valid.

the error I get with that is :

> The LINQ expression 'd => string[] { "ins", "outs", }' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

creating the array outside doesn't change anything, the error stays the same (well, the expression in the error changes, but not the main message itself)

is there a way to do that ? or do I have no other choice than creating a dummy table in the database containing my `ins` and `outs` to have the join be possible directly (if that is the only choice, what would be the best way to add that ?)

Comment: If you are ok to use third party extensions I can post sample.

Comment: Don't join. Use relations and navigation properties instead. *Don't* create the item array in the query itself either, that's what the error complains about

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv
it would depend on the extension, but I'd be willing to try to convince the others on the team if it works

Comment: Read the error message. It says `The LINQ expression 'd => string[] { "ins", "outs", }' could not be translated.` It doesn't complain about the JOIN or `?`. Create the array before running the query. EF Core only knows how to translate `Enumerable.Contains`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
could you elaborate on that ? how would I "create" records with navigation properties ?

Comment: Again, the error has nothing to do with `?`. In fact, why do you even want a LINQ query? You can duplicate rows in the client just fine. I'd even say that if you duplicate rows, you shouldn't be using an ORM at all - you aren't dealing with entities, you're working with raw data

Comment: Are you trying to *pivot* the data? That's not how it's done in SQL. And once again, it's a lot easier to do this on the client.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the issue is I then have to use the data in some other joins.  so doing it outside of the linq EFcore query would mean other queries after that to get the data I need.

Comment: Why are you using JOINs *at all*? It's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from navigation properties and the relations between objects. An ORM isn't a model of the database and LINQ isn't SQL. ORM means Object Relational Mapper. It Maps Objects to Relational constructs.

Comment: In fact, if you want help you'll have to post the *entire* query, not just snippets that make little sense by themselves. It's quite possible that the best solution is to create a view or function with the query you want and map the results to objects. Although queries like the one you posted have very bad performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so what you're saying is that the ORM is not something I can use to do what I want in this case ?
problem is, for this project, it has been decided that no DataBase access should be done without going through the ORM. am I just out of luck then ?

Basically, I do want an object out of it, but that does not exactly match the model from the Database.

Comment: What *do* you want to do? Clearly you aren't working with entities. Beyond that, one can only guess. Maybe you want to map the results to an object at the end, but clearly you aren't trying to load objects

Comment: `no DataBase access should be done without going through the ORM.` you can use `ToView` to map to a view, and `FromSqlRaw` to execute and map to a function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the project is not open source, And I cannot just put code of it on the internet like that. (plus it's a 200+ lines query, although only 40 if you don't count the select part).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you're willing I could probably try to direct message you to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow community!

You are on the right way and you only need to correct a thing in your code:

The problem is that you haven't named the variable containing data in the anonymous type:

```cs
var q = from d in data
        from type in new string[] {"ins","outs"}
        select new {
           type, 
           datas = type == "ins" ? d.ins : d.outs 
        };
```

EDIT:

The error is saying that the creation of the string array cannot be translated into SQL language...

I thought that also 'Data' table was in-memory, but I think that you cannot join 'concrete' (db) tables with in-memory ones, so I suggest to force linq to load the data before joining calling ToList() to the db table (as the error suggests):

```cs
var q = from d in Data.Tolist()
        from type in new string[] {"ins","outs"}
        select new {
           type, 
           value = type == "ins" ? d.ins : d.outs 
        };
```

If loading the enitire table into memory is a problem you can create the "ins/outs" table inside the DB and join with it...

Comment: Well, that is my bad for writing a sample of code that is not what I have in my program.
that is not the issue, the error is still present, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I would propose extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators).

Nothing in query should be changed, just add call `ToLinqToDB()`:

```cs
var q = from d in data
        from type in new string[] {"ins","outs"}
        select new {type, value = (type == "ins" ? d.ins : d.outs)};

q = q.ToLinqToDB();
```

It should create desired SQL.